# How to split multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': ['0,3788,99,20.88', '3,99022,08,91.995'],
                   'var2': ['0,929,92,299.90', '1,38333,9,993.11'],
                   'var3': ['8,9332,99,29.10', '7,922111,07,45.443']})
Out[248]: 
                var1              var2                var3
0    0,3788,99,20.88   0,929,92,299.90     8,9332,99,29.10
1  3,99022,08,91.995  1,38333,9,993.11  7,922111,07,45.443
```

I want to split each column on comma and same the new set of columns next to each other. So the resulting data frame should look like below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({('var1', 'x1'): [0, 3], ('var1', 'x2'): [3788, 99022], ('var1', 'x3'): [99, '08'], ('var1', 'x4'): [20.88, 91.995],
                    ('var2', 'x1'): [0, 1], ('var2', 'x2'): [929, 38333], ('var2', 'x3'): [92, 9], ('var2', 'x4'): [299.90, 993.11],
                    ('var3', 'x1'): [8, 7], ('var3', 'x2'): [9332, 922111], ('var3', 'x3'): [99, '07'], ('var3', 'x4'): [29.10, 45.443]})

Out[249]: 
  var1                    var2                    var3                    
    x1     x2  x3      x4   x1     x2  x3      x4   x1      x2  x3      x4
0    0   3788  99  20.880    0    929  92  299.90    8    9332  99  29.100
1    3  99022  08  91.995    1  38333   9  993.11    7  922111  07  45.443
```

The `MultiIndex` is not mandatory, but then I'd like to have an opportunity to easily gather the data and obtain df3 if needed:

```
    var  x1      x2  x3       x4
0  var1   0    3788  99   20.880
1  var1   3   99022  08   91.995
0  var2   0     929  92  299.900
1  var2   1   38333   9  993.110
0  var3   8    9332  99   29.100
1  var3   7  922111  07   45.443
```

My effort included `pd.melt` and `str.split`:

```
df_long = pd.melt(df.reset_index(drop = False), id_vars = 'index', var_name = 'var', value_name = 'values') \
    .sort_values(['index', 'var']) \
    .set_index('index')
df_long = df_long['values'].str.split(',', expand = True)
df_long.columns = ['x' + str(i) for i in range(df_long.shape[1])]
```

But:
1) I don't know how to then spread the data for different `var1, var2, var3...` next to each other 
2) transforming from wide format to long format (`df` to `df_long`) and back again (`df_long` to `df3`) seems highly inefficient and I care for performance with the seeking solution.

So what's the best way to transform from `df` to `df2`, so that we could then easily obtain `df3` if needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) , [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` , [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to achieve this:

```
final=(df.stack().str.split(',',expand=True).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
                                             .sort_index(level=0,axis=1))
print(final)
```

---

```
     var1                    var2                    var3                    
     0      1   2       3    0      1   2       3    0       1   2       3
0    0   3788  99   20.88    0    929  92  299.90    8    9332  99   29.10
1    3  99022  08  91.995    1  38333   9  993.11    7  922111  07  45.443
```

For renaming the 0th level of the columns, use;

```
final.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a,f'x{b}') for a,b in final.columns])
```

---

```
   var1                    var2                    var3                       
    x0     x1  x2      x3   x0     x1  x2      x3   x0      x1  x2      x3
0    0   3788  99   20.88    0    929  92  299.90    8    9332  99   29.10
1    3  99022  08  91.995    1  38333   9  993.11    7  922111  07  45.443
```

You can also use the below for the second output shown in your question:

```
df.stack().str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('x').reset_index(1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
  level_1 x0      x1  x2      x3
0    var1  0    3788  99   20.88
1    var2  0     929  92  299.90
2    var3  8    9332  99   29.10
3    var1  3   99022  08  91.995
4    var2  1   38333   9  993.11
5    var3  7  922111  07  45.443
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to be really efficient. One more thing - what if I would like to have variables x1 to x4 instead of x0 to x3? How can I adjust the code?

Comment: @jakes `final.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a,f'x{b+1}') for a,b in final.columns])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that gets df3 first:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df[s].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix("x").assign(var=s) for s in df])

print(df3)
```

```
  x0      x1  x2      x3   var
0  0    3788  99   20.88  var1
1  3   99022  08  91.995  var1
0  0     929  92  299.90  var2
1  1   38333   9  993.11  var2
0  8    9332  99   29.10  var3
1  7  922111  07  45.443  var3
```

And then:

```
df2 = df3.set_index("var", append=True).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print(df2)
```

```
var var1                    var2                    var3                    
      x0     x1  x2      x3   x0     x1  x2      x3   x0      x1  x2      x3
0      0   3788  99   20.88    0    929  92  299.90    8    9332  99   29.10
1      3  99022  08  91.995    1  38333   9  993.11    7  922111  07  45.443
```

Comment: I like the clarity of this solution, but seems to be less performant than the others. One more thing - what if I would like to have variables `x1` to `x4` instead of `x0` to `x3`? How can I adjust the code?

Comment: @jakes you can replace the appropriate part of the code with `df[s].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(lambda x: x+1, axis=1).add_prefix("x").assign(var=s)`